# Visual Studio 2012 HTML Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-2012, page-inspector

I have created this in VS2012.  For some reason I get the following error when I try to view it in page inspector.

**"Uh-oh, something went wrong! Error Code: 403"**

Can anyone please tell me why? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>TEsting</title>
</head> 
    <body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            text-align: right;
            width: 274px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            height: 23px;
            width: 602px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            text-align: right;
            height: 26px;
            width: 274px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            height: 26px;
            width: 602px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            height: 23px;
            width: 274px;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            width: 274px;
        }
        .auto-style8 {
            width: 212px;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            height: 26px;
            width: 212px;
        }
        .auto-style10 {
            height: 23px;
            width: 212px;
        }
        .auto-style11 {
            width: 602px;
        }
        .auto-style12 {
            width: 602px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        #Reset1 {
            width: 84px;
        }
    </style>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table class="auto-style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">User Name</td>
                <td class="auto-style8">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxUN" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style12">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxUN" ErrorMessage="User Name is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">E-Mail</td>
                <td class="auto-style8">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style12">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxEmail" ErrorMessage="Not a valid E-mail address" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2">Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style8">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style12">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxPassword" ErrorMessage="Password is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">Confirm Password</td>
                <td class="auto-style9">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxConfirmPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBoxConfirmPass" ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <br />
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="TextBoxPassword" ControlToValidate="TextBoxConfirmPass" ErrorMessage="Password does not match" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4">Country</td>
                <td class="auto-style9">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCountry" runat="server" Width="180px">
                        <asp:ListItem>Select Country</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>United States</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>United Kingdom</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Germany</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>France</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownListCountry" ErrorMessage="Select a country name" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select Country"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style6"></td>
                <td class="auto-style10">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
                    <input id="Reset1" aria-required="False" type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                <td class="auto-style3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style7">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style8">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style11">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `403` is the HTTP status code for "forbidden", so I'd say it's likely your development server is the problem, not the HTML. Look in the Visual Studio menu under `PROJECT` > `[project name] Properties...`.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,  Thank you for the response.  I can view the project properties but what am I looking to change?  Thank you!

Comment: Well, I don't know how you want it set up, so I can't really tell you what to do. I'd suggest you read through [this MSDN page on dev server options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx), then decide what you want to do. If you get stuck, you'll at least be able to ask a new, more specific question which people will be more able to help with.

Comment: Thanks for the link and appreciate the help! Hopefully I can get it setup so that it will show up in the page inspector in VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a case when this error was caused by adware activity. Scan your computer for malware, check what your proxy setting is, remove program [RocketTab](http://www.pcthreat.com/parasitebyid-37281en.html), if it is installed on your computer.

source: http://support.proboards.com/thread/509964/ip-address-banned?page=2